# Hbase Spark Connector for Cloudera 6.3.2

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase, cloudera, connector

I am trying to write a spark dataframe to Hbase 
following are the version of components I am dealing with

spark-version: 2.4.0

Cloudera distribution: 6.3.2

HBase version: 2.1.0

Scala Version: 2.11.12

Jar files used

1. **hbase-common-2.1.0-cdh6.3.2.jar**
2. **hbase-client-2.1.0-cdh6.3.2.jar**
3. **hbase-server-2.1.0-cdh6.3.2.jar**
4. **shc-core-1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11.jar**

Code

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableCatalog
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val Patient = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/vps_demo/Patient.csv")
Patient.createOrReplaceTempView("Patient_data")
val testDataFrame =
  spark.sql("select REGISTRATIONNO,PATIENTNAME,Age from Patient_data")
testDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("testDataFrame")

def catalog = s"""{
    "table":{"namespace":"default","name":"patient900"},
    "rowkey":"key",
    "rowkey":{"cf":"rowkey","col":key","type":"string"},
    "REGISTRATIONNO":{"cf":"personal","col":"REGISTRATIONNO","type":"string"},
    "PATIENTNAME":{"cf":"personal","col":"PATIENTNAME","type":"string"},
    "Age":{"cf":"personal","col":"Age","type":"string"}
    }""".stripMargin

testDataFrame.write
  .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog))
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
  .save()
```

Error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/JsonInput;Z)Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableCatalog$.apply(HBaseTableCatalog.scala:186)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation.<init>(HBaseRelation.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource.createRelation(HBaseRelation.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
  ... 76 elided
```

Can somebody please guide Why I am getting this error ?

Comment: can you post build.sbt file ?

Comment: @Srinivas ,Thanks for replying ,,Actually i have kept those 4 jar files on my local machine(linux) and have opened the spark shell like "spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/home/devadmin/shc/*" --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/devadmin/shc/*""  and later i am trying to run the code on console

Comment: ok, instead of jar files , can you pass libraries like --packages <> .. it will bring all required libraries along with dependencies.

Comment: I guess the reason for this error is a conflict in the jackson package. I had a similar problem and solved it by looking into the dependency tree resolving conflicts.

Comment: @mike ,have you done the integration of spark and hbase on cloudera 6.3.2 ? Please tellme what all jar files you have used ! I am stuck here and I desperately need help :(

Comment: could you paste your build.sbt file and also some example data? Ideally, you provide everything in your question to make it reproducible for others.

Comment: @mike i have used maven for dependency resolution..

Comment: @mike Actually mike i am not building my code,, what i am doing is i have  kept all those above mentioned jar files on my linux local and have opened my spark shell pointing to that location. and the dataframe which i am trying to write to the Hbase consists of following columns  REGISTRATIONNO,PATIENTNAME,Age ,,seeking for your help ..